# How do I return a subset of sessions that meet specific conditions?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I guess everything is in the title. How do I return a subset of sessions that meet specific conditions? or to ask my question differently how can I return sessions that meet a specific conditions without un-nesting them?

So for example return all the hits (nested) from sessions during which a purchase occurred?

Is this possible? Does it make sense? It probably as to do with STRUCK or ARRAY but still don't really understand this.

Comment: please give us more details. are you working with Big Query GA tables or Reporting API? what is a sample code you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without specific code to go on, a general query pattern for this type of issue might look like the following:

```
with selected_sessions as (
  select distinct session_id
  from dataset.sessions
  left join unnest(hits) h
  where h.event = 'purchase' -- insert your own logic here
)
select *
from dataset.sessions
inner join selected_sessions using(session_id)
```

Comment: That's the kind of answer I was looking for... but is this possible to build the same kind of query without Unnesting the hit in the sub-query?

Comment: Not really.  If it is a repeated record (which `hits` usually is, you have to unnest to access the fields (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#querying-nested-arrays).  Why are you hesitant to unnesting?

Comment: I'm not. I'm seen some queries using STRUCK or ARRAY function which seems like some kind of sub-query without unnesting but I'm jut a bit lost I guess. I need to dig this. Thanks.

Comment: `STRUCT` and `ARRAY` actually do the opposite, they are used to create the (repeated) records.  In the case of sessions/hits... each `hit` is a `STRUCT` (like a row/record in a traditional database).  `hits` (which you must `unnest`) is actually an `ARRAY` of `STRUCTS`, or a repeated record in BQ terms.  (You can also have an `ARRAY` of single items, they don't have to be `STRUCT`s.)